# How to load attributes from a file to chefspec node

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I have the following layout:

```
attributes/default.rb
recipes/my_recipe.rb
spec/unit/recipes/my_recipe_spec.rb
```

In the attributes files I have a lot of common settings likes

```
default['framework']['folder']['lib'] = '/usr/lib/fwrk'
```

I would like to use them in my chefspec, like

```
it 'install the lib if there are changes' do
    lib_path = chef_run.node['framework']['folder']['lib']
    puts(lib_path)
end
```

How can I include this file to my node from SoloRunner/ServerRunner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `.converge()` first and you'll see them in there. But remember that you almost ever parameterize your tests on the same inputs on both sides, that wouldn't be a useful test since it doesn't check if the value is what you expected it to be.

Comment: yep, I forgot to run the `converge` before accessing the node